# Create single instance by extending Application?

Tags: java, android

I want an array of string to be available in 3 different activities and I want the changes done in any activity to be reflected in all the 3 activities. So I came across the singleton and application class patterns. Somehow I prefer the application class pattern. I referred to [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/) and [this](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/).

Still I am unsure how can I create a single instance of the variable.
I have a array list of strings. How can I create a single instance of it?

Comment: please downvoters can you explain the reason for the down votes ?if no..you don't have any right to down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the Array to the Apps Application class, so you can access it from any class.

You can make a Field in the Appllication class, a String array for example

```
MyApplication extends Application {

   public ArrayList<String> myList = new ....;

   //...more stuff

}
```

you can get a reference like this

```
MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication();
application.myList = whateverStringArrayList;
```

i assume you know how to extend an application prpperly and make it run :)

Comment: wait can i do this? create a list of arrays in some activity,say 
ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList();

b=a;

Where b is a variable declared in Application class ??

please if you can provide me with 2-3 lines of code ,it will be helpful ...

Comment: thank you for the answer,i will be accepting your answer soon.can you please have a look at blackbelt's answer....??and the comments below ?

Comment: @DanielBo how you can access myList like `getActivity().getApplication().myList` without typecasting `Application` to `MyApplication`? and this needs `android:name = "packagename.MyApplication"` to be declared in manifest in application tag...

Comment: i get an error that myList is cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0):

Move the Array to the class which inherits Application class, in Manifest in `<application>` tag set `android:name` attr to this class. And then in any activity you can get the array by `((YourAppClass) getApplicationContext()).getArray()`

Comment: i tried this 
getApplicationContext().NP_List
but i am getting an error "NP_List cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: show me how you declared `NP_List` in your Application class and how do you access it in activity

Comment: ok here,i have created a question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995493/getting-error-np-list-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-or-is-not-a-fieldtrying-to

Comment: I've posted an answer, basicaly in my answer here I cast getApplicationContext() and you didn't do that

Answer (score 0):

first you can declare that ArrayList as static field in one of your Activity class...

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    public static final ArrayList<String> ARRAY_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and you can access this field in any Activity like

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityA.ARRAY_LIST.add("string");
    }
}
```

or still you can write your own single instance class like

```
public class Data {
    private static Data data;
    private final ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    private Data() {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public static Data getData() {
        if(data == null) {
            data = new Data();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

and use ArrayList in Data class in any Activity like

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Data.getData().getArrayList().add("string");
    }
}
```

Comment: smells like a lot of leak potential

Comment: @DanielBo can you explain me how it does leak? I am not making Activity as static or Context or View or Drawable as static...