# Getting error , Variable cannot be resolved to a type or is not a field

Tags: android

I want an array  to be available in 3 different activities and I want the changes done in any activity to be reflected in all the 3 activities. So I  created a class

```
public class GlobalSongList extends Application{
    public ArrayList<SongDetails> NP_List = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
    public int position;
    }
```

so that i can use this NP_List in my activities.But  when i try to use

```
getApplicationContext().NP_List =//something i want......
```

I get the error as stated above ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `getApplicaitonContext()` to your class: `((GlobalSongList)getApplicationcontext()).NP_List;`

Comment: i had tried that earlier but i was missing brackets....lol thanx for the answer,i am accepting your answer here and giving you a +1 but on the previous question,i will accept some one else's answer,as it was more detailed than yours....But i will give you a +1 there...

Comment: Will the list be different for different context ??actually i have a service which i am starting from my Activity and it is giving me index out of bound ,hence i am asking this question.......is it possible to generate the context of the activity which started the service without passing the context ??

Comment: You can call getApplictaionContext from service and you should get the same array instance

Comment: ok...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996784/stackoverflowerror-runtimeexception-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

You need to typcast `Application` to `GlobalSongList`..,

```
   GlobalSongList songsList = (GlobalSongList)getApplication();
   songsList.NP_List = ...
```